# How to access People album used in Apple's Photos app

Tags: ios, ios10, apple-photos

Apple's Photo app has facial recognition capabilities. I would like to know if an API exists to access the associated data for photos which have been classified by the app.

Comment: Have you figured out an answer to this in the last 4 years?  Does Photo Kit allow access to the facial identification part information?

Comment: Has anyone spoken with Apple about accessing the facial recognition data for limited use cases on-device?

Answer (score 1):

Apple released an SDK for accessing Apple Photos called [Photo Kit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit). In the documentation, you will find API access to the photos application and photos cloud. However, if you are looking for an HTTP API I do not believe one has been announced publicly.

If you only need access to is data on Photos MacOS app I would recommend digging through the SQLite photos.db located in the photos library database directory.

```
/Users/[yourUserName]/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database/photos.db
```

I am working on a project this weekend that requires similar face data and will document my progress. Here is a sample SQLite query you can use to get all faces, photos, and corresponding person:

```
SELECT *, RKFace.modelId AS fId
FROM RKFace
JOIN RKMaster ON RKMaster.modelId = RKFace.imageModelId
LEFT JOIN RKFaceGroup ON RKFaceGroup.modelId = RKFace.faceGroupId
LEFT JOIN RKFaceCrop ON RKFaceCrop.faceId = RKFace.imageModelId
LEFT JOIN RKFacePrint ON RKFacePrint.faceId = RKFace.imageModelId
LEFT JOIN RKPerson ON RKPerson.modelId = RKFace.personId;
```

I hope this helps. :-)

Comment: How could we do that in iOS ?

Comment: This will not be possible on iOS as the security model won't let you access Apple-internal data.

Answer (score 1):

The file `photos.db` mentioned by Adrian unfortunately did not contain the data anymore in 2021. However, I found a big file called `/Users/[yourUserName]/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database/Photos.sqlite` that looked promising. Here's an SQL query that will return all photos of myself as an example:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ZPERSON.ZFULLNAME AS FULL_NAME, ZGENERICASSET.ZFILENAME AS FILENAME, ZGENERICASSET.ZDATECREATED + 978307200 AS DATECREATED
FROM ZPERSON
INNER JOIN ZDETECTEDFACE ON ZPERSON.Z_PK=ZDETECTEDFACE.ZPERSON
INNER JOIN ZGENERICASSET ON ZDETECTEDFACE.ZASSET=ZGENERICASSET.Z_PK
WHERE ZPERSON.ZFULLNAME LIKE "Christian%"
ORDER BY ZGENERICASSET.ZDATECREATED DESC
```

The returned columns are `FULL_NAME`, `FILENAME` and `DATECREATED`. The resulting date is specified as a Unix timestamp in seconds, though it may also contain a fraction. For example, `1618068987.64944` refers to `3:36:27 pm UTC | Saturday, April 10, 2021`.

For reference, `978307200` is the difference between the Apple epoch and the Unix epoch in seconds. I obtained it in Python through this expression: `(datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0) - datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)).total_seconds()`.

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone spoken with Apple about accessing the facial recognition data for limited use cases on-device?