# Apple Photos: Get list of “face albums” from Photos.app

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I’d like to make an app where you pick a face from Apple’s Photos app, and the app explores those photos on a map.

So far, I’ve figured out that this query returns a single `PHCollectionList` named “People”:

```
let peopleFolder = PHCollectionList.fetchCollectionLists(
  with: .smartFolder, 
  subtype: .smartFolderFaces, 
  options: nil).firstObject!
```

... but I don’t see a way to get the faces inside this folder. Here are the queries I’ve tried so far:

```
let people1 = PHCollectionList.fetchCollections(in: peopleFolder, options: nil)
let people2 = PHCollection.fetchCollections(in: peopleFolder, options: nil)
let people3 = PHAssetCollection.fetchCollections(in: peopleFolder, options: nil)
```

...but all three of these return empty `PHFetchResult`s.

**Is there a way to get a list of the Faces in a user’s Photos library?**

Comment: Hey Bryan did you get any further with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no! Still hoping there's a way to do this, but haven't gotten a working solution.

Comment: It's my question too.

Comment: @bryanjclark after all these years, I have no the same question and I cannot solve it. did you make any progress?

Comment: @Tobonaut I never did! But I haven’t tried since then either, so perhaps something has changed since then!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that Apple does not want application access to this information as it is highly private information. I suggest to file a radar and hope that they open this up with some application privilege in a future macOS version.

Another option is to access the sqlite database file from the Photos library directly on disk (as suggested here [How to access People album used in Apple's Photos app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869608/how-to-access-people-album-used-in-apples-photos-app)), but the internal format can change at any time.